# unravelling a function of a meshgrid back into a coordinate array (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

**Problem:**

I have two 1D arrays

```
import numpy as np 

x = np.arange(5, 9)
# array([5, 6, 7, 8])

y = np.arange(3) 
# array([0, 1, 2])
```

and another 2D array with the shape of the cartesian product of these first two (like a meshgrid of them):

```
z = np.arange(x.size*y.size).reshape(x.size, y.size)

# array([[ 0,  1,  2],
#        [ 3,  4,  5],
#        [ 6,  7,  8],
#        [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

I would like to form the following array using pure numpy:

```
coords = []
for i in range(x.size):
    for j in range(y.size):
        c = [x[i], y[j], z[i,j]]
        coords.append(c)
del i, j, c
coords = np.array(coords)

# array([[ 5,  0,  0],
#        [ 5,  1,  1],
#        [ 5,  2,  2],
#        [ 6,  0,  3],
#        [ 6,  1,  4],
#        [ 6,  2,  5],
#        [ 7,  0,  6],
#        [ 7,  1,  7],
#        [ 7,  2,  8],
#        [ 8,  0,  9],
#        [ 8,  1, 10],
#        [ 8,  2, 11]])
```

**Background:**

One could see this as

```
x1, y1 = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = f(x1, y1)
del x1, x2
```

where `f` is some function. I would then like to construct the array

```
coords = [[x[1], y[1], z[1,1]], [x[2], y[1], z[2,1]], ...]
```

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `np.c_[x1.ravel('F'),y1.ravel('F'),z.ravel()]`?

Comment: Or with `y1,x1 = np.meshgrid(y,x)`, then `np.c_[x1.ravel(),y1.ravel(),z.ravel()]`.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar. I did not find the duplicate! Appreciate the mark and the answer